# Do not have write permissions on '/usr/local/share/man/man3'

Tags: linux, perl

I am using Linux machine and getting YAML not installed error while installing JSON Perl module from Cpan. Any help is highly appreciable.

```
cpan[1]>install JSON

anifying blib/man3/JSON::backportPP::Boolean.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/JSON::backportPP.3pm
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/usr/local/share/man/man3'
Do not have write permissions on '/usr/local/share/man/man3'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 13
  MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.90.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- NOT OK
----
  You may have to su to root to install the package
  (Or you may want to run something like
    o conf make_install_make_command 'sudo make'
  to raise your permissions.Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
```

and when I try to install YAMl, I get this error .

```
cpan[1]>install YAML


ERROR: Can't create '/usr/local/share/man/man3'
Do not have write permissions on '/usr/local/share/man/man3'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 13
  INGY/YAML-1.15.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- NOT OK
----
  You may have to su to root to install the package
  (Or you may want to run something like
    o conf make_install_make_command 'sudo make'
  to raise your permissions.Warning (usually harmless): 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Failed during this command:
 TYEMQ/Algorithm-Diff-1.1903.tar.gz           : install NO
 NEILB/Text-Diff-1.43.tar.gz                  : install NO
 INGY/Spiffy-0.46.tar.gz                      : install NO
 INGY/Test-Base-0.88.tar.gz                   : install NO
 INGY/Test-YAML-1.06.tar.gz                   : install NO
 INGY/YAML-1.15.tar.gz
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state` is harmless.

Comment: As for not having permission to writing to `/usr/local/share/man/man3`, any reason to believe that's incorrect? If you do have root access, did you follow the instructions in the error message?

Comment: ..and if you don't, are you asking how to install modules to an arbitrary directory? I'd use `perlbrew` to install a `perl` in your home directory instead.

Answer (score 7):

`'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state` is harmless.

As for not having permission to writing to `/usr/local/share/man/man3`, any reason to believe that's incorrect?

If you do have root access, did you follow the instructions in the error message? Launch cpan, and execute the following commands:

```
o conf make_install_make_command 'sudo make'
o conf commit
```

If you don't have root access, are you asking how to install modules to an arbitrary directory? I'd use [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::perlbrew) to install a `perl` in your home directory instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. 
I tried your commands but don't think it worked. 
cpan[2]> conf make_install_make_command 'sudo make'
Unknown shell command 'conf'. Type ? for help.

Looks like I don't have root privileges.. Can I install modules without root access ?  Sorry for asking such a basic question. I am new to perl :)

cpan[3]> conf commit
Unknown shell command 'conf'. Type ? for help.

Comment: You left out the "o"

Comment: oh my bad, I tried again ..
cpan[5]> o conf make_install_make_command 'sudo make'
    make_install_make_command [sudo make]
Please use 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!


cpan[6]> o conf commit
commit: wrote '/scratch/paasqa/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm'

Comment: The changes were successfully made. The next time you use `cpan`, it will run `sudo make install` instead of `make install`

Comment: Change `sudo make` to `make`, but you shouldn't want to

Answer (score 1):

Are you running cpan as a regular user? No sudo or root access? That's probably why.

Comment: Bad advice. No need to run `cpan` itself as root. The advice in the error message the OP posted is better.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I add the following in the ~/.bashrc file.

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Then add these right after the definition of "PERL5LIB":

PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base "/home/usrname/perl5""; export PERL_MB_OPT;

PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/usrname/perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;

Save, quit, and source the file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Maybe you can use the below command to get the above information in terminal:
`perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib`